# Hide main Octave window while running script that shows a plot

Tags: windows, octave

I am currently displaying a plot using a script run from the Windows command line successfully. Is there a way to hide the main Octave window (GUI or CLI), but still show the plot and any message boxes?

Comment: ... are you asking if you can programmatically, from within octave, control the parent terminal from which octave was called?

Comment: Not the terminal that Octave is called from (Windows cmd in this case), but the main Octave window that is opened after calling Octave. It would be ideal if it was possible from a cmd line argument or from Octave itself, but if there are other methods, I'm interested.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I'm following 100%, but, you can launch octave in the console rather than in the gui. I usually work on linux but I assume the windows installation provides an octave-cli executable too. And if you don't want to have to open a terminal to run your script, you can create a windows launcher that runs this command for you from a desktop icon. But neither the octave gui nor the terminal you launched octave from would be easily manipulable, since this is functionality belonging to the operating system. (it's not something you typically expect in other languages / IDEs either)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am actually running C++ code that calls the cmd line and executes the code necessary to call Octave. This causes the Windows cmd terminal to open very briefly and close after calling Octave with the parameters that I want to use to run my script and create my plot. This would be nice for the CLI or GUI as well while still being able to keep the plot open. It makes sense that they would not be easily manipulable, though. Just wanting to see if there is a way to do it.

Comment: Ok, I see! Now we're getting somewhere :)  What do you call exactly in C++? Is it the octave executable directly via a 'system' command? Or are you actually calling the 'cmd' executable and instructing it to run octave in the resulting terminal?

Comment: I am calling it via a 'system' command.

Comment: and you are definitely calling the octave-cli.exe executable rather than the batchfile?

Comment: The beginning of the command I'm using is: %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\wscript.exe "c:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\octave.vbs" --no-gui

Comment: there you go, this may be your issue then. octave.vbs is not the octave executable per se, it is simply a VisualBasic script which opens a terminal and uses that to call the executable. The executable for the cli interface itself lives in `c:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli.exe`. You could try calling that and see if it executes your script directly without opening a child-terminal.

Comment: I have now tried calling the cli exe directly (as well as the gui exe) using the 'system' command, and it doesn't show the figure at all now. Running the same command from a batch file works similarly to how it did before, so I'm fairly certain the script is at least running. I tried using pause and uiwait in the Octave script to prevent it from closing before the figure is displayed.

Comment: that's odd. maybe octave-cli tries to use a different graphics toolkit ... what about if you call octave.exe instead of octave-cli.exe, and pass the --no-gui option? (even though, if you're using the octave executable specifically to run a script, then it shouldn't be launching the gui _anyway_ ... ).  Btw, it's worth pointing out that there's an actual C++ library / interface to octave, that allows you to call an octave function directly from c++ programmatically. Presumably this is the right way to do what you're trying to do, though possibly a bit more of a hassle to figure out ...

Comment: Where would "octave.exe" be located? I did a search for it in "C:\Octave", but did not find it. I am aware of the C++ interface, but wanted to see if there was a way of doing this without having to use it. We also want people to be able to use MATLAB in a similar way, so that would be a bit of extra work. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: it would be in the same folder as octave-cli.exe, so in your case, presumably there exists a `c:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\mingw64\bin\octave.exe`  (assuming you have a 64-bit windows installation)

Comment: Hmm... it's not in that folder. That is the folder where the cli and gui executables are (along with a few other "octave-" executables).

Comment: The "gui executable" (presumably `octave.exe`) is what I'm referring to. If you are at a terminal and you run it by itself, it will launch a gui. But if you use this to interpret a script (e.g. `octave.exe myscript.m`), then this just runs the script, and no gui is launched. And also, if you run it by itself with the --no-gui option, it should not launch a gui either. In theory `octave-cli.exe` should be the same as `octave.exe --no-gui`, but in practice the former may set some different defaults that are more appropriate to terminals (e.g. it sets gnuplot as the default plotting program).

Comment: Also, you may have to quote your system call appropriately in the code, so that `"c:\bla\bla\bla\octave.exe myscript.m"` is interpreted as one command rather than two.

Comment: I see. The gui executable for me is "octave-gui.exe". I have been trying to use that with --no-gui as well. As you say, when I run from a batch file, it does produce slightly different graphics for the plot than "octave-cli.exe", but has similar behavior. Trying to rearrange the quotes in the system call (as well as in my batch file) doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I don't think I can help debug this further then ... I expected this would work. Out of curiosity, if you create a shortcut that calls the octave executable on your script, and then launch it from your desktop, does that work? (assuming you're still using the `waitfor` command at the end of your octave script)

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway! I tried to create a shortcut, but the command I use is too long to fit the target.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat prova.m 
x=1:20;
plot(x)
pause(5)
```

the graph is plot and the CLI is never shown

```
$ octave-cli prova.m
```

[image]